# Jump to anchor after post

Tags: express, keystonejs

I'm using Keystone.js and I put an Enquiry form at the bottom of the page. It is basically just a copy of the example provided by the Keystone Generator for the contact.js view. I can get it to submit properly and also display errors, however after the submit the browser puts me on the top of the page. Is there a way to jump to an anchor on a page after posting to the Enquiry?

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Enquiry = keystone.list('Enquiry');

exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res),
        locals = res.locals;

    // locals.section is used to set the currently selected
    // item in the header navigation.
    locals.section = 'home';
    locals.enquiryTypes = Enquiry.fields.enquiryType.ops;
    locals.formData = req.body || {};
    locals.validationErrors = {};
    locals.enquirySubmitted = false;

    // On POST requests, add the Enquiry item to the database
    view.on('post', { action: 'contact' }, function(next) {

        var newEnquiry = new Enquiry.model(),
            updater = newEnquiry.getUpdateHandler(req);

        updater.process(req.body, {
            flashErrors: true,
            fields: 'name, email, phone, enquiryType, message',
            errorMessage: 'There was a problem submitting your form:'
        }, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                locals.validationErrors = err.errors;
            } else {
                locals.enquirySubmitted = true;
            }
            next();
        });

    });


    // Render the view
    view.render('index', {layout:''});

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with HTML. Just had to put the anchor in the form's action.

```
<form method="post" action="#contact">
```